# CryptographicException when trying to log in/make a user

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've made (in a group), and I've deployed it to googles app engine. Through Visual Studio 2017 "Publish to Google Cloud..."

The problem here is I can't login. Our login system uses Steam OpenId to login and create the user. The user itself is just an extended applicationUser with a few special values.

And I get this error in the error reporting:

When I click the button that forwards to Steams OpenId login page, i write my Steam Login information normally, I get returned to the "finish making account" (adding username and email), but after that it doesn't work. and seemingly nothing happens.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {94b75804-c807-4225-9cd4-871a28ad72b3} was not found in the key ring.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize
```

Edit: Not sure if releveant, but we do have two dbContext. The standard ApplicationDbContext and one of our own creation